# How to get rid of the "chapter" word with \leftmark?

Tags: chapters, fancyhdr

I'm using fancyhdr to make customs headings and I would like to know if there is a way to get rid of the "chapter" when I use \leftmark in my header ? 
The document is in oneside report.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using `titleps`, that comes with `titlesec` instead.You would have to write something like that  in your preamble:

```
\usepackage[pagestyles][titlesec}
\newpagestyle{custom}{%
\titlerule
\sethead{}{\thechapter.~\chaptertitle}{\thepage}
\setfoot{}{}{}
}%
\pagestyle{custom}
```

This will produce a header with the number and title of current chapter centred,  page number on the right and a text-wide rule under these elements. If you don't want a rule, don't write the command for it. If you prefer the page number centred in the footer, write it as

```
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
```

Comment: It worked well, thank you !
More of that, it look likes titleps can do more things than fancyhdr.

Comment: I'm not sure it can do *more*  things, but I think it's easier or more intuitive to use (you don't have to struggle with marks if you don't want to).